# How to auto-save pictures opened in tabs with one click

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In Google Chrome, how can I auto-save pictures in all open tabs at once, or with one click?

Is this possible? I don't want to lose time for saving all the pictures in their tabs.

Answer (score 7):

None of these suggestions were exactly what I wanted, so I wrote up a quick chrome extension to do it:

[**Save Tabbed Images**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-tabbed-images/hhcoikfhkkadkgklepjkfgafmjoggefh)

[image: Save Tabbed Images]

Just click on the extension and it'll find all the images opened as tabs in the current window. Then it's just one click to download them all to your default Downloads folder.

Comment: Sadly, link is now dead.

Comment: https://github.com/kevinsqi/save_tabbed_images/releases

Answer (score 5):

Now you can't do this without an add-on, but what I suggest to you is never get there in the first place. If you want or need to download a link without "tabbing it", just use the ever handy quick download Chrome does, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + left-click.

Just use this for any image you come across that can be clicked to open a new link (aka full-size).

Comment: Too bad it doesn’t help for non-linked images.

Answer (score 2):

There is this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/afjaicccalbbickikgdegaihmajaidpd) that let's you save images with one click.

It's called "I'm a Gentleman".  From the description:

> Save images with one click using a hotkey or download all images from
>   a webpage using the extension button.

Answer (score 1):

This chrome extension worked pretty well for me when I tried it. Has multiple Modes as well for image downloading/saving from multiple windows, tabs, same site, etc.

[Bulk Download Images](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gfjhimhkjmipphnaminnnnjpnlneeplk)

Answer (score 1):

when you place your mouse on image which you want to download, just press S it will download automatically